# Looking for most efficient way to 'deploy' single wordpress page to multiple external subdomains

Tags: multisite, subdomains

Wondering if there might be a more efficient way to deploy a single wordpress landing page to ~30 or more external subdomains.

Basically....
We have created a WP page that we want to replicate with minor customisations and then deploy this page to a 3rd party Subdomain. It's a product landing page that 3rd parties will be hosting.

In an ideal world we would be able to manage all of these pages in a single WP install then come up with a way of distributing them - yet maintain our ability to edit in our WP instance.

I had thought that there might be a way to Map the 3rd party's Subdomain to a single WP page on our server.

e.g.... http://Subdomain.Domain.com.au would map to http://www.MyDomain.com.au/theirLandingPage.php. The client would map to our server then we would handle a redirect to the specific page via .htaccess or something to that effect.

Having asked in another thread I'm not sure this is possible.

Other not-so-great solutions I'm considering are:

1. Send each client a version of the entire WP site to host on their
   subdomain - it will mean managing 30+ WP sites.
2. Export each page as a static HTML page with something like WP2Static which would then be sent via FTP to their Server and unzipped.
3. Have them do a redirect so http://Subdomain.Domain.com.au becomes http://www.MyDomain.com.au/theirLandingPage.php - this may cause issues for the client
4. We use Multisite with /subdirectory structure and they map their Subdomain to that directory - Not sure this is possible either is mapping to a page is not possible (!?)

Any suggestions welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about using an iframe? your client uses iframe to host your page in the landing page, while you have the ability to maintain wp yourself? consider fullpage iframe

Comment: I did think of that but come from an old school of belief that all iFrames are the evil spawn of satan...? :-)

Possibly unfounded....

Comment: Im not so sure of that. it depends. however, for the moment thats what came to mind

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a multisite wp install and manage updates with a plugin like Broadcast. Not sure if their free version or the Pro enables the overwriting of existing content with mother blog post updating, so it can easily get distributed to all network blogs. And of course, you can this way map each network sub to client domain or subdomain.

Elementor Pro enables custom parameters so you can send to the same lander but have certain text on it dynamically change depending on the link visitors get.

Unless you're testing CRO for domain names or to make it look like it's different domain sources for the campaigns. Useful for SEO and if you run ads or other types of marketing with high burn rates where multiple domains need to be deployed.

With FunnelFlux you will have drag and drop funnels supporting all types of traffic [email/PPC/search, etc], rich tracking, conditional redirects, split testing and more and custom CNAME domains supported while you track what's going on.

If it's whitehat landers you give your affiliates AffiliateWP plugin might be a good solution in addition to Elementor Pro.

Another alternative - Static HTML landers.
If you need a good fast EASY drag and drop HTML builder check out the PixFort bootstrap HTML builder - hosted online and works best from a windows machine [not mac or win on mac]. Can even do pops with multi-steps and has a lot of nice drag and drop elements plus can edit HTML code when needed. I made a great lander for FB ad campaign and had an 80% CR optin on it.

Use CF [cloudflare] free account; setup DNS, tweak settings and set a few free rules alongside free SSL cert [or flexible SSL].

For the static lander - add .htaccess with caching optimizations in there for max effect and page load speeds.

PixFort and also other builders like Weber or Gum are found on ThemeForest.net  Can place the HTML pages on S3 buckets, various free hosting yada yada.

Comment: Can you please offer a solution with either code or at the very least not include paid plugins? Thanks!